# How to copy last but one modified file using batch file/powershell?

Tags: batch-file

For example I have 4 folders and I want to copy only Last but one modified folder.
Is there a way to copy only one folder instead of all the folders?
Currently I using batch file to copy paste last modified file as shown below:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir "Sourcedir"/b /ad-h /t:c /od') DO SET a=%%i
echo Most recent subfolder: %a%
pause
xcopy "Destinationdir" "Sourcedir\%a%\" /o /x /e /h /k
```

Answer (score 2):

try like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir "." /b /ad-h /t:c /od') DO (
 set "prev=!last!"
 set "last=%%i"
)

echo %prev%
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. this has resolved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to try something along these lines:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "Directory="
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B /AD /O-D /TW "Sourcedir"'
) Do Set "Directory=%%A" & GoTo :CopyIt
:CopyIt
If Defined Directory XCopy "SourceDir\%Directory%" "DestinationDir\" /E /H /X /Y
```